# Cassandra data aggregation

Tags: sql-server, cassandra, aggregate-functions

I have an existing reasonably large SQL Server database and an analytics application that uses that to perform data aggregations based on user input. For instance the application can visualize queries like 
`select ... group by Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5`. The user can then switch the column groups however they want so nothing is static.

Things currently work ok however we are rapidly getting more data and things are starting to not work as good.

We have investigated Cassandra and want to move in that direction for a number of reasons however it is not clear how to allow users to do GROUP BY type queries in a fast manner.

Do we need to pre-aggregate all combinations of the data? If so this sounds like we may need `x!` combinations for this to work. That could be quite a bit of precalculation work. Spark may help but I doubt that is going to be sub second fast across a cluster.

Comment: Not an answer, but this might help: https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-cql/cql/cql_using/useCreateUDA.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a JIRA on the GROUP BY clause that may eventually come in Cassandra: 
[CASSANDRA-10707](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10707)

Combined with User Define Aggregated and [CASSANDRA-10783](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10783) (Allow literal value for UDF) it may even be possible to simulate GROUP BY ... HAVING xxx

It all looks quite promising, provided that those JIRA get into the trunk

Comment: Thanks. Currently it seems that if I wanted to group by then I would have to create a User Defined Aggregate function and the data would all have to be in the same partition?